# How can I copy part of the huge file to new file?

Tags: windows

I would like to copy part of huge text file (tens of GB) into new smaller file, starting from the certain offset in percentage to the end, or from beginning 5%. Can that be done with a simple command in Windows?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Windows 10, you can use *Ubuntu-Bash cmd* otherwise you might want to use [Unix-GNU-Utils-for-Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)

Once you'll install it, you'll be able to use unix `head` and `tail` commands, and redirect the output into a new file

- `head -100` (or any number of lines)
- `tail -100` (or any number of lines)

In order to get the amount of lines in the file, you can use Unix `wc -l` command

```
wc -l filename.txt
```

After you get the number of lines in this file, you can multiple the number with 5/100 in order to get the amount of 5%, and use this result in the `head` or `tail` commands
e.g.

```
head -100000 file1 > file2
```

[man head](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

> ```
> head - output the first part of files
> -n, --lines=[-]K 
> print the first K lines instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
> ```

[man tail](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)

> ```
> tail - output the last part of files 
> -n, --lines=K
>     output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
> ```

[wc man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)

> ```
> wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file 
> -l, --lines
>     print the newline counts
> ```

Comment: Any way to specify percentage?

Comment: @pablo - you can use `wc -l` to get the length of the huge-file, and calculate the percentage using num-of-lines * (5/100)

Comment: @Yaron That will only be accurate if all of the lines are the same length ...

Answer (score 0):

Really easy way - use `more` and redirect the output:

- `giantfile.csv` - your existing huge file
- `smallfile.csv` - new "small" file you're creating

Type in and hit enter:

```
more giantfile.csv > smallfile.csv
```

Hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> a couple of times to get some output redirected to the new small file. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd> to exit the more command. Once you do that, you'll have a new small file with the top of the exiting file in it.